# Getting the previous cells of a given data range

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I try to get the previous cells of a given range. So far my code looks like this:

*Get the selected range and pass it to another method*

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = this.ExcelAppObj as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = null;

range = app.get_Range(this.DataRangeTextBox.Text);
var caption = ExcelHelper.GetRangeHeaderCaption(range);
```

*The following method is executed*

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Gets the range header caption of a given range.
    /// The methode goes through every previous cell of the given range to determine the caption.
    /// If the caption can not be determined the method returns an random string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="selectedRange">The selected range.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetRangeHeaderCaption(Range selectedRange, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application excelApp)
    {
        // The caption of the range. The default value is a random string
        var rangeCaption = ExcelHelper.getRandomString(5);                      

        // Check if the provided range is valid
        if (selectedRange != null && excelApp.WorksheetFunction.CountA(selectedRange) > 0)
        {
            var captionNotFound = true;
            Range rangeToCheck = selectedRange.Previous;

            // Go to each previous cell of the provided range 
            // to determine the caption of the range            
            do
            {
                // No further previous cells found
                // We can stop further processing
                if (rangeToCheck.Cells.Count == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                //System.Array myvalues = (System.Array)rangeToCheck.Cells.Value;
                System.Array myvalues = (System.Array)rangeToCheck.Cells.Value;

                rangeToCheck = rangeToCheck.Previous;

            } while (captionNotFound);
        }

        return rangeCaption;
    }
```

At the point

```
var rangeToCheck = selectedRange.Previous;
```

the property access throws the following exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Die Previous-Eigenschaft des Range-Objektes kann nicht zugeordnet werden.
```

**What i want to achieve:**
Go through all previous cells of the given data range containing double or int values and get the header caption by check if the previous cell is a numeric value or a string. If the cell contains a string return the string to the caller.

**Edit #1**
Maybe this is an important information. The method GetRangeHeaderCaption is implemented in another class. It is not included in the class where i get the the range by using the Excel Interop.

**Edit #2**
Found the problem. 
The property Previous returns the previous **LEFT** cell of the given range. For example, if my range has the address B2:B16 the previous property returns the address A2. So if i try to access the Previous property of A2:A16 i get the exception because there is no column before the column A.

But what i need is that if i have the range B2:B16 i need to get the content of B1. Can you follow me so far?

Comment: check whether SelectedRange has some valid value and is not null

Comment: @Akansha: Extended the method by to get the range header caption by using an if statement to validation. Still no change

Comment: Debug on the value of the "Rage" if the range is [0,0] then there will not be a previous cell.

Comment: I think i found the problem but it does not help me to get this thing done. See my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay then, i used my brain and worked out a solution for this problem. Its a workaround and i don't know if there is another way or better way to solve this - see my code here:

```
    using XLS = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

         /// <summary>
    /// Gets the range header caption of a given range.
    /// The methode goes through every previous cell of the given range to determine the caption.
    /// If the caption can not be determined the method returns an random string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="selectedRange">The selected range.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetRangeHeaderCaption(Range selectedRange, XLS._Application excelApp)
    {
        // The caption of the range. The default value is a random string
        var rangeCaption = ExcelHelper.getRandomString(5);

        // Check if the provided range is valid
        if (selectedRange != null && excelApp.WorksheetFunction.CountA(selectedRange) > 0)
        {
            // Get the included cells of the range
            var rangeCells = selectedRange.Address.Split(new char[] { ':' });
            // Get the beginning cell of the range
            var beginCell = rangeCells[0].Trim();
            // Get the column and row data of the cell
            var cellColumnRow = beginCell.Split(new char[] { '$' });
            // Split the beginning cell into the column and the row
            var cellColumn = cellColumnRow[1];
            var cellRow = Convert.ToInt32(cellColumnRow[2]);

            var captionNotFound = true;
            int i = 0;
            // Go to each previous cell of the provided range 
            // to determine the caption of the range            
            do
            {
                // Check if the next cell would be invalid
                var nextCellRow = cellRow - i;
                if (nextCellRow == 0)
                    break;
                // Create the cell coordinates to look at
                var cellToLook = string.Format("{0}{1}",
                                                cellColumn,
                                                nextCellRow);
                // Get the value out of the cell
                var cellRangeValue = ((XLS.Worksheet)((XLS.Workbook)excelApp.ActiveWorkbook).ActiveSheet).get_Range(cellToLook).Value;
                // ...just to be sure it does not crash
                if (cellRangeValue != null)
                {
                    // Convert the determined value to an string
                    var cellValue = cellRangeValue.ToString();

                    double value;
                    // Check if the cell value is not a numeric value
                    // Check if the cell value is not empty or null
                    if (!double.TryParse(cellValue, out value) &&
                        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cellValue) &&
                        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cellValue))
                    {
                        // In this case we found the caption
                        rangeCaption = cellValue;
                        captionNotFound = false;
                    }
                }

                i++;

            } while (captionNotFound);
        }

        return rangeCaption;
    }
```